# Getting 400 error code when I run axios get request?

Tags: javascript, axios

I write some code to getting info

```
const stock = await Stock.find({
    exchange: exchange
});
// Here stock array length is 5300

stock.forEach(async (stockEl) => {
    const EOD_API = process.env.EOD_HISTORICAL_API
    const {data} = await axios.get(`https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/${stockEl.code}?api_token=${EOD_API}&filter=General::Industry`);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Here I place get request for every stock array element by `forEach` function. Then it give me error like image-
[Click to see images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfG6c.jpg)

But When I place it outside of forEach function like this-

```
const EOD_API = process.env.EOD_HISTORICAL_API
const {data} = await axios.get(`https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/${stockEl.code}?api_token=${EOD_API}&filter=General::Industry`);
console.log(data);
```

Then it gives no error. For Remembering Stock has 5300 element, that means axios run 5300 times.

Any solution or idea?

Comment: forEach is not promise-aware. Use a for loop instead. [Explanation and examples here](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/). In that forEach all the 5k requests are firing at once. That's why you're getting 400.

Comment: for loop? Have I to run for loop?

Comment: I think you can try a couple of things to debug it, first of all print out `stockEl.code` just to see the value. Then you can run your code setting `stock` as an array on 1 element and see if this works as yor code outside the forEach. Another things, you don't need to set `EOD_API` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a few changes:

- Replace forEach with for because forEach is not promise aware
- Use try, catch => catch any errors
- Use Promise.allSettled => it allows you to run all promisses together without waiting each other which in return will enhance your app performance. It returns an array with status ("fulfilled", "rejected")

  ```
  const fetchSingleStockElement = async (stockEl) => {
        try {
            const EOD_API = process.env.EOD_HISTORICAL_API,
                { data } = await axios(

  `https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/${stockEl.code}?api_token=${EOD_API}&filter=General::Industry`
                );
            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    };

    const fetchAllStockData = async () => {
        let promisesArray = [];
        try {
            //fetch stock array
            const { data } = await Stock.find({
                exchange: exchange
            });

            //fetch single stock
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                promisesArray.push(fetchSingleStockElement(data[i].id));
            }

            const results = await Promise.allSettled(promisesArray);
            console.log('results', results);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('results error', err);
        }
  ```

  };

Here is a working example with fake API of 4466 entries:

```
const fetchSingleAirline = async (airlineId) => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios(`https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines/${airlineId}`);
            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
    };

const fetchAllAirlineData = async () => {
    let promisesArray = [];
    try {
        const { data } = await axios('https://api.instantwebtools.net/v1/airlines');
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            promisesArray.push(fetchSingleAirline(data[i].id));
        }

        const results = await Promise.allSettled(promisesArray);
        console.log('results', results);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('results error', err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing await in forEach doesn't hold the process since forEach is not promise-aware. Try this instead:

```
(async () => {
    for (let index = 0; index < stock.length; index++) {
        const EOD_API = process.env.EOD_HISTORICAL_API
        const {data} = await axios.get(`https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/${stock[i].code}?api_token=${EOD_API}&filter=General::Industry`);
        console.log(data);
    }
})();
```

[More information](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/).

Comment: Getting the same error. Any other solutions

Comment: Are you getting all the console.log back at once or is there some delay between them? Replace the api with something else and see if you get anything different like [this api](https://api.sampleapis.com/futurama/info). I also edited the answer.

Comment: There are no delay between them, I get all console at  a time.